# kernel debug with a vmware machine

Tags: windows, debugging, windbg

I am using windbg to begin a kernel debug with a vmware windows machine. I referred to

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff538143(v=vs.85).aspx.

But I didn't succeed. I had two question about it.

1). After I start windbg by such a command:

```
**windbg -k com:port=\\10.57.43.22\pipe\debug,pipe**
```

It will show:

```
**Fail to open \\10.57.43.22\pipe\debug
Kernel debugger failed initialization, Win32 error On1326
"Logon failure: unknown user name or bad password"**
```

What is the reason? There is no space for me to type user name or password.

2). In the msdn article, it said :

**In the virtual machine, configure the COM port to map to a named pipe.**

I had added a serial port which used a named pipe on vmware virtual machine. How to map a COM port to a pipe?

Answer (score 10):

Serial and network debugging are two different things.

To debug a VMWARE virtual machine, once you have added the COM port to the VM, then in the VM settings:

[image: COM Port settings]

Notice:

- The name of the named pipe is `\\.\pipe\com_port` (you can use whatever you want after `\\.\pipe\`)
- The COM port number is **2** (see in the picture where it is mentioned "**Serial Port 2**" on the left pane)
- The two dropboxes with `this end is the server` and `the other end is an application`.

According to the documentation, about "Yield CPU on Poll":

> This configuration option forces the affected virtual machine to yield
>   processor time if the only task it is trying to do is poll the virtual
>   serial port.

Don't forget to configure the Windows VM with bcdedit:

```
bcdedit /debug on
bcdedit /dbgsettings serial debugport:2 baudrate:115200
```

Restart your VM once this is done. In this case I use the serial port 2 (usually, the first COM port in VMWARE is used by the printer).

Start Windbg with a command line like this:

```
windbg -k com:pipe,port=\\.\pipe\com_port,resets=0,reconnect
```

Or, once on Windbg, use CTRL+K, then:

[image: Windbg COM Port settings]

You should be able to kernel debug your VM.

Comment: The vmware vm is located on another physical machine. So the windbg still set port as \\.\pipe\com_port?

Comment: I just wanted to say that this is the only tutorial that I have found that works perfectly with vmware workstation for kernel debugging. I believe the key here is that you are using com2 instead of the common com1. Vmware doesn't make this very clear.

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/a/72202531/2330143 to do this with secure boot on

Comment: Thanks, this works for me. 